# AngularJS - How do I modify variables in $rootScope?

Tags: angularjs, web, rootscope

I've got a potentially really dumb question, but how do I modify variables up in $rootScope in Angular? I've got a slide-in sidebar that I want to change the content on whenever someone clicks on a thumbnail, and I figured the easiest way to handle where the data in the sidebar comes from/the sidebar visibility would either be in global values, or in $rootScope. I'm trying to keep everything as simple as possible, but I just don't know how to handle modifying global variables.

My angular code surrounding this is:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.currentUrl = { value: 'visual/design/1/' };
    $rootScope.detail_visible = { value: true };
});

app.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 
    function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.isDetail = $rootScope.detail_visible.value;
    $scope.url = $rootScope.currentUrl.value;
    $scope.hide = function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.detail_visible.value = false;
    };
}]);
```

and the connecting HTML is

```
<div id="detail_box" ng-class="{d_show: isDetail, d_hide: !isDetail}">
    <a href="#" class="box_close" ng-click="hide()"></a>
    <div ng-include="url + 'detail.html'"></div>
</div>
```

In essence, I'm trying to make it so that when you click on a thumbnail, it changes the currentUrl value from 'visual/design/1/' to whatever they've clicked on (like, 'music/solo/2' or whatever) then changes the value of detail_visible to false, so that the classes on my sidebar switch and I get a nice little slide-in, with fresh content loaded via ng-include which I kind of love a thousand times more than I thought I would. I've been banging my head against this for about three hours now, breaking everything else on this app whenever I get the chance. What am I screwing up here?  Alternatively, is there a better way of doing this?

My reason for using global variables is that I have multiple thumbnails in multiple controllers, and I want each one to be able to dynamically change the URL in my ng-include.

Comment: Object properties of scopes are inherited -- in your controller, you should be able to modify `$scope.detail_visible.value` and see it affect the $rootScope. You still have to initialize it on the $rootScope in `.run()` though.

Comment: See, I figured that as well, but clicking on the a link in question isn't doing anything; I thought maybe I just had to change $scope.detail_visible to $rootScope.detail_visible but it still does nothing.  I guess my question should probably be "why doesn't this ng-click actually work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, you change the $rootScope variable simple by referencing it with

```
  $rootScope.detail_visible.value = newValue;
```

but you dont need to inject $rootScope to your function:

```
  $scope.hide = function() { //without $rootScope
    $rootScope.detail_visible.value = false;
};
```

**But,** I would suggest you to implement a service and not to pollute the rootscope for such task.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

Object properties of scopes are inherited -- in your controller, you should be able to modify `$scope.detail_visible.value` and see it affect the $rootScope. You still have to initialize it on the $rootScope in `.run()` though.

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.currentUrl = { value: 'visual/design/1/' };
    $rootScope.detail_visible = { value: true };
});

app.controller('navController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.hide = function() { // don't need to pass an argument
        $scope.detail_visible.value = false;
    };
}]);
```

view:

```
<div id="detail_box" ng-class="{d_show: currentUrl.value, d_hide: !currentUrl.value}">
    <a href="#" class="box_close" ng-click="hide()"></a>
    <div ng-include="currentUrl.value + 'detail.html'"></div>
</div>
```